# DependencyProperty refreshing only one time

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom control with DependencyProperty

```
public Point EndPoint
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(EndPointProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EndPointProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndPointProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EndPoint", typeof(Point), typeof(Speedometer), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(100,100),FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

and somewhere in DefiningGeometry logic I'm calling

```
EndPoint = new Point(xEnd, yEnd);
```

In xaml, where I use this, I have another control and I'm trying to bind Canvas.Left to EndPoint.X of my custom control

```
<Rectangle Fill="White" Height="50" Width="50" x:Name="Grip" Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=EndPoint.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=EndPoint.Y}">
```

Update seems to be fired only once, because result depends of DependencyProperty default value. 
How to make it updating all time when value of property is changed?

Comment: You should have two double dependency properties instead. X and y

Comment: You're wrong. It can be working when dp is Point. Anyway, I tried this approach

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I got it.

First, I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in my custom control, then after set Property, I'm calling `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EndPoint));` I thought DependencyProperty can notify property changes two way.

Comment: This is not necessary and wrong. The problem is that you update the property "*somewhere in DefiningGeometry logic*". If you edit your question and show what you're actually doing, you might get a useful answer.

Comment: So, where I should update that property instead of place where it should be updated? :P